# Hide and show table columns by Checkbox check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im new to programming, just a junior for now. I have list of checkboxes. And when I uncheck a checkbox, I want that particular column to disappear from front-end. Simply to say, I have a table with some data in it. Lets say it has 3 columns, and when i uncheck 2 of them, those 2 columns should disappear. Here is a code sipped of mine, for now, it saves unchecked checkboxes to LocalStorage. Thank you for any advises and tips!
Really appreciate if you can show m a good direction to move :D

```js
export default () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [onOkClick, setOnOkClick] = useState(false);
  const [isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isDataTable, setDataTable] = useState(true);
  const [isDefaultChecked, setDefaultChecked] = useState(true);
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState();
  const [isColumn, setColumn] = useState(true);
  const [hiddenColumns, setHiddenColumns] = useState([]);
  const [Checked, setIsChecked] = useState([]);
  
  const onCheckboxChange = (key: string, value: boolean) => {
    console.log(key, value);
    // const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hiddenColumns"));

    if (!value)
      setHiddenColumns((hiddenColumns) => [...hiddenColumns, { label: key }]);
    else setHiddenColumns(hiddenColumns.filter((x) => x.label !== key));
  };
  
  return (
  <Dialog
          isOpen={isDialogOpen}
          onOkClick={() => {
            localStorage.setItem(
              "hiddenColumns",
              JSON.stringify(hiddenColumns)
            );
            console.log(hiddenColumns);
            setDialogOpen(false);
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => setDialogOpen(false)}
   >
    <div>
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked={isDefaultChecked}
              label="Delivery methods"
              onChange={(value) => onCheckboxChange("delieveryMethods", value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked={isDefaultChecked}
              label="Delivery Date"
              onChange={(value) => onCheckboxChange("delieveryDate", value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked={isDefaultChecked}
              label="Organization Name"
              onChange={(value) => onCheckboxChange("organization", value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
          <APIDataTable<Mail>
          apiPath="/edo/chancellery/maildoc_extinc"
          params="?on_marking=true "
          type={Mail}
          columns={[
            new Column<Mail>({
              label: "Delivery Methods",
              render: (row) => {
                return "";
              },
            }),
            new Column<Mail>({
              label: "Delivery Date",
              render: (row) => {
                return row.incomingDateText;
              },
            }),
            new Column<Mail>({
              label: "Organizaion Name",
              render: (row) => {
                return row.organizationNameOrFullName;
              },
            }),
          </div>
  )
  };
```

Comment: could you share a working sample ? (there are missing dependencies here). The way you structure your state could be enhanced to easen this 'hide column' action.

Comment: cant share full working sample, coz im using a lots of components imported to that file, sorry. That snipped consists only the elements that is needed for logic/structure, thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `hiddenColumns` state type to object and set the boolean value to the proper key. e.g. `{ delieveryMethods: true }`. Also, separate `columns` for filtering operations. Check below for detail.

```js
  // ...
  const [hiddenColumns, setHiddenColumns] = useState({});
  // ...

  const onCheckboxChange = (key: string, value: boolean) => {
    console.log(key, value);
    // const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hiddenColumns"));
    setHiddenColumns(prev => ({...prev, [key]: value}));
  };

  const columns = [];

  if (!hiddenColumns['delieveryMethods']) {
    columns.push(
      new Column<Mail>({
        label: 'Delivery Methods',
        render: row => {
          return '';
        },
      }),
    );
  }
  if (!hiddenColumns['delieveryDate']) {
    columns.push(
      new Column<Mail>({
        label: 'Delivery Date',
        render: row => {
          return row.incomingDateText;
        },
      }),
    );
  }
  if (!hiddenColumns['organization']) {
    columns.push(
      new Column<Mail>({
        label: 'Organizaion Name',
        render: row => {
          return row.organizationNameOrFullName;
        },
      }),
    );
  }
```

```html
<APIDataTable<Mail>
  apiPath="/edo/chancellery/maildoc_extinc"
  params="?on_marking=true "
  type={Mail}
  columns={columns}
/>
```